# markRollbackOnly() is not working in Camel 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, apache-camel, rollback

I have a requirement where I have to delete the file from the server and then delete it from the database.
I am using apache camel and spring boot.
I am using `transacted()` method in Apache Camel Route but the `markRollbackOnly()` method deletes the file if there is any error from DB.

My route looks like

```
from(RouterConstants.DIRECT_DELETE_FILE)
    .onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .setBody(simple(RouterConstants.EXCEPTION_PROPERTY))
    .to(RouterConstants.BEAN_GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_METHOD_GENERIC_EXCEPTION_HANDLER)
    .to(RouterConstants.ROUTE_WRITE_AS_JSON)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .markRollbackOnly()
    .end()
.routeId("directRouteDeleteFileId")
.transacted()
    //1. sftp delete
    .to(RouterConstants.DIRECT_ROUTE_SFTP)
    //2. db delete
    .setBody(header("id"))
    .convertBodyTo(Long.class).throwException(new RuntimeException())
    .to(RouterConstants.ROUTE_DELETE_FILE_FROM_DB);
```

and when I use `rollback()` it does stop the deletion of the file from the server but it does not give a proper message to end-user and throws `org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.RollbackExchangeException`

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the sequence of execution. The DB delete works fine with the markRollbackOnly() method. The SFTP does not rollback the file delete when markRollbackOnly() is used but the database delete does.